# How do I add background images inside my xterm windows?

Tags: xterm, x-windows

I am monitoring an application running on a couple of servers. I've already color-coded the xterm backgrounds in order to make it more clear which shells are running on which server. I'd like to take this one step further and use background images with some sort of text/logo combination that identifies the specific application or module running in that specific xterm.

I'd like something maintained, current, and reliable. If it was already installed on CentOS, that would be even better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `gnome-terminal` you can create profiles which include background images and select the profile when you launch it:

```
gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=PROFILENAME
```

You could also probably manipulate the XML files programatically:

```
~/.gconf/apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Profile0/%gconf.xml
```

Comment: I like this one a lot - and as a bonus, it is already installed in CentOS.

Answer (score 0):

Eterm is definitely the way to go if you're looking for customized backgrounds, IMO.